# In Django Admin changelist view, how to make a foreign key column sort by a value other than primary key?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a table with a Many-to-One relationship to itself, facilitating a tree structure:

```
class Medium(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label
```

In the Django Admin changelist view, I would like show a second column with the parent medium's label for context - and I would like the column to be able to sort based on the label.  However, if I use `list_display` to add field 'parent', that column sorts by the primary key.

Demonstration:

```
@admin.register(Medium)
class MediumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('label', 'parent', 'parent_id')
```

[image]

What's the correct or most elegant way of accomplishing this?  I've seen suggestiongs to do it by adding a custom method to MediumAdmin that returns the parent label, and then apply the @admin.display(ordering='parent__label') decorator to it, but I feel like I'm missing a more correct way, since this is surely a common need.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
@admin.register(Medium)
class MediumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('label', 'parent', 'parent_id')
    ordering = ('parent__label',)
```

This is the way i do it and it has always worked so far.

Comment: That would apply the ordering at all times in addition to the ordering caused by clicking on a column header.  What I want is to be able to click on the Parent column and have all rows sorted alphabetically by the value of the parent's label.